# Do I have to use nullable properties in app, even if I need whole data?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit, android-room

I have an app, which using `retrofit`, and `room`. As far as I know (but still learning) it is nice practice, to keep things nullable, so it'll be easier to test later on. Now, I have a question:

Do I have to make properties for both of the libraries nullable, even if I need whole object in case of `room`, and most of the `retrofit` response?

The app won't work in case there will be lack of the data in database, but I also uses 'regular' objects, like

```
val myObj = MyObj(...)
```

With `retrofit`, I do not need whole data from the response, but most of it. I'm kinda lost in it.

Comment: The opposite is true. You should avoid nullability wherever possible so the mode fits the behavior and you don’t have to defensively program around the possibility of null everywhere. Can you link somewhere you saw that advice? Maybe the application of that advice is different than how you interpreted it.